# what is the relation between operating systems and automata theory?

Tags: operating-systems

I want to do some research on how machine theory (automata theory) is applied in the operating system. Also thank you for introducing useful links and books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about direct application of automata theory to operating systems in general or even OS kernel as a whole, but pretty much every kernel subsystem that manages some resource implements a (finite) automaton.

For instance a process (or a thread) has a number of states like "running", "ready" and "blocked", and a process scheduler moves each process between these states. As an example of a transition, a timer interrupt moves a process from "running" to "ready" in a preemptive multitasking system.

Similarly I/O descriptors have states like "open", "closed", "can read", "can write". And TCP/IP sockets famously have somewhat complicated state diagram :)

[image: TCP state diagram]

I couldn't immediately find illuminating references on these topics, but I suspect classic OS books spend some time explaining the connection. On the other hand due to obvious reasons major OS kernels (like Linux or FreeBSD) much more concerned with efficient implementation than clear connection to automata theory. But I would take a look at seL4 — they have *formal proofs* of certain properties, and I bet some of the proofs rely on automata properties. :)